# Google Map V3 Panning/Dragging gets stuck once cursor goes to outer element

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using a google map in a particular section of my page.

I encounter a problem that when I click on mouse(without releasing) and start dragging mouse and go out of the map element area to other div elements outside and release the mouse on them. After coming back on the map even when the map is released , dragging/panning keeps on occuring. I have to press mouse click again to stop this.

Can someone provide help as to what event to call to stop this from happening?

Comment: This sounds more like a problem with the browser or google plugin than anything you can correct with your code. Which browser are you using? Have you checked for solutions on SuperUser or WebApps stackexchange sites?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say without seeing your code.

However, I would assume that is not the default behavior, for as far as I can tell, the issue you mentioned does not happen on [this demo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#EventsOverview), as well as other demos one the developers.google.com/maps site.